# chrome console $0 gives me a function instead of selected HTML element

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

As per this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/the-currently-selected-dom-node), in chrome console, `$0` gives current selected node in console but for me it gives function instead of html element.

[image]

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Page script has precedence over console API so `$0` is defined somewhere in the running script. Or maybe you accidentally reassigned `$0` in devtools console.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are right. This is happening only on specific website. On other websites, it is working as expected. Thanks.